# Git rebase flow

Tags: git, version-control, workflow

I am new to git and I want to start doing things 'properly'. I quite like this flow:

```
git checkout -b featurebranch
git commit -m "some changes" // manytimes
*
git pull // update master to origin's head
git checkout featurebranch
git rebase master // rebase my feature branch
git checkout master
git merge featurebranch --no-ff // keep branch and merge to master
```

But the problem I got is that I would like `push` changes somewhere where the `*` is and it brings some complications finishing my `featurebranch`. Simply put I can't push rebased branch  because 'it is behind...'. Deleting remote `origin/featurebranch` or `git push -f` I consider as workarounds. Is there something wrong on my flow or just in my understanding to git?

I want to:

- avoid epic merge
- avoid branch hell (*)
- avoid fast-forward (see commits gruped by branches)
- backup/share my local branches (*)

I could solve this by forget one of *. Is it necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebasing published commits [is strongly discouraged](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing#The-Perils-of-Rebasing). In short, when you rebase you create completely new commit objects with different IDs (hashes).

If you wish to publish your feature branch as you are working it is much better to `merge` it when you are done instead of rebasing.